# Android Jetpack navigation A ->B->C->A

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I couldn't find anything online so here I am. I'm using the jetpack navigation component and I want to navigate from `fragmentA` to `fragmentB`, and then `fragmentB` will navigate to `fragmentC`, but when pressing hw back button I want to go back straight to `fragmentA`. is this possible with the current release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with adding `popUpTo` to your action where you move from B -> C.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
    android:name="com.ballboycorp.anappaday.navigationtest.FragmentB"
    android:label="fragment_b"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragmentB_to_fragmentC"
        app:destination="@+id/fragmentC"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentA" />
</fragment>
```

What that means is

> From B move to C and when user clicks back button, move back to A.

You should navigation to C using that action instead of giving destination id.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentB_to_fragmentC)
}
```

Visually this is how it looks

[image]

Comment: hmm, somehow it's not doing it, still goes back to fragmentB even with the app:popUpTo="@id/fragmentA"

Comment: do I manually have to call navigate(..) or is the back button suppose to automatically go back to fragmentA?

Comment: @ElJazouli sorry for confusion. I edited the answer and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

With the Navigation Component you can handle `onBackPressed` on fragments. In your `onViewCreated` of fragment `C` just add this line of code:

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                view.findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.fragmentA, false)
            }
        })
```